# angular-cli: How to compile all scss files into a single css file

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-cli, node-sass

I am learning to use sass for my angular2 components like this:

```
@Component({
  ...
  styleUrls: ['./app.home.scss', './app.mixins.scss'],
  ...
})
```

This works perfectly fine and I am able to render the changes in the web page that is run using `ng serve`.

However when I build the project using `ng build` I expect all `scss` files to compile and build into a single `css` file that can be included in `index.html`. Currently none of the `scss` files are compiling with build. So how do I ensure that my `scss` files are compiled with build in a single `css` file? Is there something that can be specified in `angular-cli.json` that will enable this?

Comment: you might want to check WebPack. It can bundle all ts into an JS file and all SCSS into 1 CSS file. 

* https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Comment: But, my question is why do you want to do this?
If I understood your concern: just add them as partials (mixins, variables) and import them in the scss file.